# Multiple If statement logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I have a bit of an issue with some jQuery logic I'm making so I've included the code below. I have the first if statement checking the screen resolution, the 2nd if statement is checking how many list items there are and to only run if 1 or more and the final if statement making sure that only 1 instance of the append is running as it's inside an AJAX request so had issues with multiple instance being output.

Any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong? Any help would be awesome, thank you :)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="swatches color clearfix">
    <li class="selectable">
        <span class="swatchanchor js-swatchanchor js-colorswatch">
            List Item 1
        </span>
    </li>

    <li class="selectable">
        <span class="swatchanchor js-swatchanchor js-colorswatch">
            List Item 2
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
if($(window).width() >= 1358){
    var $lis = $('ul.swatches.color li');
    var $jsColorMsgCheck = $('.jsColorMsgError');



    if ($lis.length > 1) {
      if ($jsColorMsgCheck.length) {
        $(".swatches.color").parent().append($('<div class="jsColorMsgError">PLEASE SELECT A COLOUR</div>'));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to nest you can simply use `&&` operator

Comment: Your logic seems fine. Have you checked to see which condition is/is not passing?

Comment: is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah, no console errors showing for me and it still doesn't work with the && operator either, I can't seem to get the logic to work with both variables, it works with one or the other, but not together :/

Comment: @NickElse can you show us a demo fiddler

Comment: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/YgyRVJ

Comment: We would need some more information to help you solve the problem. First: when is the above code called? Second: I assume that you create an element with class `jsColorMsgError` dynamically inside some other function? Could you include these parts of your code as well?
Just had a look at your pen and I can't see where you would set the `jsColorMsgError` in your code.

Comment: Have a look at a [fork of your pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGXzye?editors=1111#anon-login). I simply added a hidden input with the proper class to show that your code is working as expected.

Comment: @NickElse basically in the pen `$jsColorMsgCheck.length` is 0 what is `jsColorMsgError` ?

Comment: @SaschaM78 That looks spot on that mate!

Comment: Nice :-). But to give you a really working solution, we would need to also see where your mentioned AJAX call comes into play. Basically what I assume is: you fill the list of list items somewhere dynamically (e.g. with AJAX) and then later-on want to check if any elements have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the logic you're trying to do, there are two things you might have got mistaken:

1)

> the 2nd if statement is checking how many list items there are and to only run if 1 or more

To check for 1 or more your if should be

```
if ($lis.length >= 1) {
```

since `$lis.length > 1` would be 2 or more.

2)

> the final if statement making sure that only 1 instance of the append

If you want to execute the code only if there's no `.jsColorMsgError` div, you can use

```
$jsColorMsgCheck.length == 0
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoyOYN?editors=1111

Comment: Well observed, the first check would expect two elements to exist. The second check in the author's code would also work in the existing setup as `0` would be interpreted as `false` inside of an IF statement.

Comment: Absolutely spot on that mate! Thank you for your help :)